# iOS APNs Push Notifications - Development

Tags: ios, ios6, apple-push-notifications, pem

I would like to use development certificate to send push notifications but it doesn't work.
I have generate the SSL certificate but when is use it on php this is the result

> [03-May-2014 14:02:15 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning: 
>   stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   (Connection timed out)

I tried to create the file. pem several times but never goes well.

For generating the pem file I performed the steps as described on Apple Documentation.

What is the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your server can access to apple servers ?

Try with telnet:

> telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

If the answer is yes, my advice is to follow that tutorial to be sure that your pem file is well generated: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 (Go to "Making a PEM File" chapter)